# Why this template class works, despite using std::less oddly

Tags: c++, std

This code works:

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr static auto less = std::less{};

#include <string>

std::string a = "1";
std::string b = "1";

int main(){
    std::cout << ( less( 6, 3 ) ? "Y" : "N" ) << '\n';
    std::cout << ( less( a, b ) ? "Y" : "N" ) << '\n';
}
```

According en.cppreference.com, std::less is implemented like this:

```
template<class T>
struct Less{
    constexpr bool operator()(const T &lhs, const T &rhs) const{
        return lhs < rhs;
    }   
};
```

but if this is true, how `std::less{};` works? It will require to pass the type - `std::less<int>{};`

Alternatively, if implementation is like this:

```
struct Less{
    template<class T>
    constexpr bool operator()(const T &lhs, const T &rhs) const{
        return lhs < rhs;
    }   
};
```

everything will works.

But if this is like it is, why use `class` and not `lambda`?

Strangely enough, but this code also works:

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr static auto less = std::less<int>{};

#include <string>

std::string a = "1";
std::string b = "1";

int main(){
//  obviously for strings it no longer works.
//  std::cout << ( less( 6, 3 ) ? "Y" : "N" ) << '\n';
    std::cout << ( less( a, b ) ? "Y" : "N" ) << '\n';
}
```

So what is really going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since C++14 `std::less` is declared as

```
template< class T = void >
struct less;
```

and it has a [specialization for `void`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less_void) that has an `operator()` with the form of

```
template< class T, class U>
constexpr auto operator()( T&& lhs, U&& rhs ) const
  -> decltype(std::forward<T>(lhs) < std::forward<U>(rhs));
```

This `operator()` deduces the types of the parameters for you and returns `lhs < rhs`.  This is what allows your first code block to compile.

In your second example you switch `less` to be

```
constexpr static auto less = std::less<int>{};
```

and this forces you to have comparator that only works for `int`s.

Comment: Let me see if I understood correctly, 
if T is something, you can compare only this type.
and if  T=void, there is specialization and you can compare anything with anything else (as long is comparable). See code I will post

Comment: @Nick Correct.  `less<>` is a generic functor for doing `a < b`.